# What expression would satisfy these conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 variables `length` and `num`. `num` can be 0, 1 or 2. `length` can be 2 or 3.

Let me setup the conditions:

- If `num` = 0 and

  - `length` is 2, the result should be 0.
  - `length` is 3, the result should be 0.
- If `num` = 1 and

  - `length` is 2, the result should be 1.
  - `length` is 3, the result should be 1.
- If `num` = 2 and

  - `length` is 2, the result should be 1.
  - `length` is 3, the result should be 2.

Thought I stated the question in the title, but it seems like it was not clear. So let me try to clarify:

What expression / function would satisfy these conditions? I.e., in case of a function, takes to arguments and gives the desired result :)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Exactly, what's the question?

Comment: additionally, that's only 2 variables, not 3.

Comment: @Anadactothe Typo, sry.

Comment: @asd I'm glad you fixed that, but this is still just a statement. Include some sort of question in the body of the text or people will flag to close this as off topic.

Comment: The question is what expression would satisfy the requirements as I stated in the title :) I.e. some function that takes two arguments and then gives the desired result.

Comment: @asd to a mathematician's understanding of the word "function", you've already completely described the function. if you're interested in a a certain type of function (linear in the variables? a polynomial in the variables?), you would need to specify that.

Comment: @asd ditto to gregory, but i must ask, why is this tagged [linear-algebra] ?

Comment: $\lceil num·length/4 \rceil$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a lot of people pointed out in the comments, there is currently no real question.

I will try to interprete and answer your text:

### Definition of functions

A function is a special type of map. A map is formally defined as a set of ordered pairs (which can but doesn't have to be given by algebraic expressions). Thus your text already fully defines a map simply as the set $\{((0,2),0), ((0,3),0), \ldots, ((2,3),2)\}$ (this map maps a subset of say $\mathbb Z ^2$ into a subset of $\mathbb Z$.)

### Interpolation

If you want to have say a polynomial from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ which satisfies your finite amount of discrete conditions, you can use some interpolation techniques like the [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Consider for example ($x$ corresponds to `num` and $y$ corresponds to `length`) $$P: \mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow\mathbb R: (x,y) \mapsto (2-x) \cdot x + \frac{x \cdot (x-1)}{2} \cdot (y-1).$$

$P$ is a polynomial in two variables satisfying your "boundary conditions".

Comment: Thanks, you understood the question right. But your function yields 4 when x=2 and y=3, which is opposed to the desired result 2

Comment: We have $P(2,3) = (2-2) \cdot 2 + \frac{2 \cdot 1}{2} \cdot (3-1) = 0 + 1 \cdot 2 = 2$. I am not sure how you got $4$.

Comment: Oh, I am just blind haha.

Comment: But how did you get to that formula?

Comment: See for instance [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Essentially I can constructed polynomials which are $0$ at $0$ and $2$ (i.e. $(2-x)\cdot x$) and $1$ at $1$ (note that $0,1,2$ are the values that num takes.) Similarly, $\frac{x\cdot (x-1)}{2}$ is $0$ in $0,1$ and $1$ in $2$. Then you multiply these with polynomials that satisfy the conditions on $y$.